# Pass AsyncTask result to onCreateView in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, oncreate

Here is my situation:
In my onCreate(), I would like to create an AsyncTask to retrieve data for a WebService and store it in an ArrayList(Retrive points for graph).

Then in my onCreateView(), I would like use ArrayList and iterate over it to plot points...

I would like some way to make sure that I wait for the AsyncTask to finish executing before starting the onCreateView() function. Then I used callback in onPostExecute but its not working. I read about using get() on the task, but If I use get() method UI will be blocked.So only possible way to use callback method in onPostExecute.

But my code is running like this before completing Aysnctask  onCreateView executed and getting NullPointer Exception at this line if(PF.size() != 0).

```
package hello.aws.graphs;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import hello.aws.login.WebService;
public class PFGraph extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncTaskCompleteListener {

public static boolean errored = false;
static ProgressDialog dialog = null;



public static Menu menu;

static ArrayList<PFKVABean> PF;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_line_chart);

     getData();/*Getting data from webservice**/



    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }


}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent newIntent;



    switch (item.getItemId()) {



        case R.id.bb_menu_favorites:
        getData();/*Getting data from webservice**/

            break;

        case R.id.bb_menu_recent:
        getData();/*Getting data from webservice**/

            break;

        case R.id.bb_menu_recents:
            getData();/*Getting data from webservice**/

            break;
}
    return true;

}
public void getData()
{

    AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS(this);

        task.execute();

}


@java.lang.Override
public void onTaskComplete(Object result) {
    PF=(ArrayList)result;//Storing result of AsyncTask
    Log.e("check","check");
}


/**
 * A fragment containing a line chart.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    private LineChartView chart;
    private LineChartData data;



    private int numberOfLines = 2;

    private boolean hasLines = true;
    private boolean hasPoints = true;
    private ValueShape shape = ValueShape.CIRCLE;
    private boolean isFilled = false;
    private boolean hasLabels = false;
    private boolean isCubic = false;
    private boolean hasLabelForSelected = false;




    public PlaceholderFragment() {



    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);



        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pf_graph, container, false);

        chart = (LineChartView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chart);
        chart.setOnValueTouchListener(new ValueTouchListener());


        generateData();


        return rootView;
    }


    private void generateData() {

        chart.setZoomEnabled(true);

        chart.setZoomType(ZoomType.HORIZONTAL);

        List<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();
        List<AxisValue> axisValues = new ArrayList<AxisValue>();

        if(!errored) {
            if (PF.size() != 0) {/******NULL Pointer Exception***/

            /****Here the logic for plotting the points on graph***/

        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error occured in invoking Webservice", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
}


private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList> {
    private AsyncTaskCompleteListener<ArrayList> callback;

    public AsyncCallWS(AsyncTaskCompleteListener<ArrayList> cb) {

        this.callback = cb;
    }

    @java.lang.Override
    protected ArrayList doInBackground(String... params) {
        PF=WebService.GetWSData();
        return PF;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(PFGraph.this, R.style.MyTheme);

        dialog.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Small);

        dialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cp_bar));

        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
       // getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();



    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList PF) {

        if(dialog!=null||dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Log.e("v","v");
            callback.onTaskComplete(PF);//Sending result
        }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: first of call AsyncTask and onPostExecute(result) call your fragment with Result in PlaceHolderFragment.newInstance(YourClassToSend)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the call to `generateData();` from `onCreateView()` to `onTaskComplete()`, so that it gets called only after array is filled.